# Como abrir um documento do Word protegido por senha?

Tags: java, arquivo, microsoft-word

Eu consigo abrir normalmente um arquivo ***.docx*** no Word usando o `desktop.open` do java, mas tem um caso que preciso abrir o documento que é protegido com senha e o Word abre pedindo a mesma. Existe alguma forma de eu digitar a senha ainda no programa e ao abrir o documento ele já abra sem pedir?

Parte do código que estou usando:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    try {
         Desktop desktop = Desktop.getDesktop();
         File file = new File("" + caminhofonte1global.getSelectedFile());  
         desktop.open(file);                    
    }
    catch (IOException ioe) {
         ioe.printStackTrace();
    }           
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Acredito que usando somente o [**`open`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/Desktop.html#open-java.io.File-) não seja possível, pois você precisa checar a senha e o método apenas lança a aplicação associada para abrir o tipo do arquivo. No entanto existe a [**POI**](https://poi.apache.org/) que é uma API da Apache para manipular documentos da Microsoft.

```
public static void main(String...args) throws
        FileNotFoundException, IOException, GeneralSecurityException {

    final Path ARQUIVO = Paths.get("C:\\word.docx");
    final String SENHA = "foo";

    FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(ARQUIVO.toFile());
    POIFSFileSystem pfs = new POIFSFileSystem(fis);

    Decryptor decryptor = Decryptor.getInstance(new EncryptionInfo(pfs));

    if (decryptor.verifyPassword(SENHA)){
        // Abre o arquivo se a senha estiver OK.
    }
}
```

Comment: Eu ja estava procurando e lendo sobre esse Apache mas não tinha entendido como funcionava a abertura com senha. Muito obrigado!